# My readers don't have Digg or StumbleUpon, how can I ask them for help raising my SERP?

Tags: google-search

I have a coupons-code web *page* that receives 40,000 unique visitors a month, but its numbers are stagnant or dropping because it is #3 in Google's SERP.  75% of its visits are new and the page has been around since 2007.

I sincerely think my resource is helping people and I sincerely think I am loads better than #1 and #2 because I have the freshest coupons and I have no ads -- so I am at my wit's end on how to raise my SERP.  The rest of the sites in #4, #5, etc., are huge coupon broker sites so I really have no chance pursuing link exchanges.  Meanwhile, the site in #1 and #2 is also a small guy who also have been around since 2007.  None of them update their coupons page near as often as I do.  (The #1 guy updates once a month. :( )

My readers do not use Digg, StumbleUpon or Twitter, or have blogs of their own.  I tried Facebook's Like button and tweet reader comments via bit.ly but got no SERP improvement.

How can a site ask readers help to raise its SERP?  Or any suggestions?

Comment: This would be better on [WebMasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Comment: It seems like your problem isn't a low SERP position but a really high bounce rate. If you consistently get 30,000 new visitors each month, but your return visitors stay at 10,000 month after month, then that means almost all of your new visitors are not interested in coming back to your site.

Comment: @Lèse - I'm guessing that's because it's a single-serving site. You come, see what you want, get it, and you've got no reason to be returning to the site. Perhaps that's a better question to be asking...

Answer (score 2):

Usually social networks play hardly any role on your SERP rankings. Social networks are places where people see your links, not search engines.

You should order a link building campaign to boost your SERP positions. Also, you should contact someone to make a SEO analysis for your website.